# how to dynamically parse a json column in a dataframe without knowing its schema in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Given a spark dataframe which has a column which may or may not contain nested json . This nested json is dynamic . The end requirement is to break the json and generate a new dataframe with new columns for each keys present in nested json.

The json is dynamic so the table generated will be dynamic. Please also consider that the dataframe consists of more than 100 million records.

eg-

**Input**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id         |key     |type      |value 

|f9f          |BUSI    |off         |false                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|f96          |NAME    |50          |true                                                                                                                                                                                                           
|f9z          |BANK    |off         |{"Name":"United School","admNumber":"197108","details":{"code":"WEREFFW32","studentName":"Abhishek kumar","doc":"certificate","admId":"3424325328","stat":0,"studentDetails":false} }|
```

**Output** :-

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id   |key    |type     |value  |Name    | admNumber   |code    | studentName  | doc   |admId    |stat   | studentDetails
+------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------                              

|f9f  |BUSI    |off     |false  |NULL    |NULL         |NULL    |NULL          |NULL   |NULL     |NULL   |NULL |                                            
|f96  |NAME    |50      |true   |NULL    |NULL         |NULL    |NULL          |NULL   |NULL     |NULL   |NULL            |                                                                                                                
|f9z  |BANK    |off     |NULL   |United School    |197108         |WEREFFW32    |Abhishek kumar          |certificate   |3424325328     |0   |false |
```

Comment: Does your initial Dataframe have only one json column?

Comment: Do you wanted all nested keys to become columns? (Flattened?) 
Give an example input and output.

Comment: if you don't know schema there will be lot of performance impact. or if you know schema before you can easily improve performance to some extent.

Comment: @ziad.rida  yes , initial dataframe has one json column and all nested keys needs to become columns . The nested json would not be more than 3 or 4 level deep.

Answer (score 0):

```
  val data = Seq(
    (77, "email1", """{"key1":38,"key3":39}"""),
    (78, "email2", """{"key1":38,"key4":39}"""),
    (178, "email21", """{"key1":"when string","key4":36, "key6":"test", "key10":false }"""),
    (179, "email8", """{"sub1":"qwerty","sub2":["42"]}"""),
      (180, "email8", """{"sub1":"qwerty","sub2":["42", "56", "test"]}""")
  ).toDF("id", "name", "colJson")

  data.show(false)
//  +---+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
//  |id |name   |colJson                                                        |
//  +---+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
//  |77 |email1 |{"key1":38,"key3":39}                                          |
//  |78 |email2 |{"key1":38,"key4":39}                                          |
//  |178|email21|{"key1":"when string","key4":36, "key6":"test", "key10":false }|
//  |178|email8 |{"sub1":"qwerty","sub2":"42"}                                  |
//  +---+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+


  val schema = spark.read.json(data.select("colJson").as[String]).schema
  val res = data.select($"id", $"name", from_json($"colJson", schema).as("s")).select("id", "name", "s.*")
  res.show(false)
//  +---+-------+-----------+-----+----+----+----+------+----+
//  |id |name   |key1       |key10|key3|key4|key6|sub1  |sub2|
//  +---+-------+-----------+-----+----+----+----+------+----+
//  |77 |email1 |38         |null |39  |null|null|null  |null|
//  |78 |email2 |38         |null |null|39  |null|null  |null|
//  |178|email21|when string|false|null|36  |test|null  |null|
//  |178|email8 |null       |null |null|null|null|qwerty|42  |
//  +---+-------+-----------+-----+----+----+----+------+----+

  val  df1 = res.filter('sub1.equalTo("qwerty"))
  df1.show(false)
//  +---+------+----+-----+----+----+----+------+----+
//  |id |name  |key1|key10|key3|key4|key6|sub1  |sub2|
//  +---+------+----+-----+----+----+----+------+----+
//  |178|email8|null|null |null|null|null|qwerty|42  |
//  +---+------+----+-----+----+----+----+------+----+
```

Comment: can this also be applied for nested json?